# How to set Order By ASC/DESC from a Variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having an issue here when I try to use `Order By` by column index (numeric value).

This Works:

```
  @OrderBy = 1

  SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM Table ORDER BY @OrderBy ASC
```

This Doesn't Work:

```
  @OrderBy = 1
  @Direction = 'ASC'

  SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM Table ORDER BY @OrderBy @Direction
```

How do I use the order by direction from a variable when ordering by the numeric column number?

Comment: What does that do? You can't store the `ASC` or `DESC` in a variable without it being a string.

Comment: i dnt think it is possible excep case when **OR** dynamic quesry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
  case when @Direction = 'ASC' THEN field END ASC ,
  case when @Direction = 'DESC' THEN field END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ORDER BY @OrderBy CASE @Direction WHEN 'ASC' THEN @OrderBy ELSE -@OrderBy END ASC
```